# HttpWebRequest Exception The remote name could not be resolved: 'http'

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

```
  System.Net.WebException: The remote name could not be resolved: 'http'
       at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
       at Helpers.CheckUrl(String url)
```

My code:

```
try
        {
            if (IsURLValid(url))
            {

                Uri requestUri = new Uri(url);
                HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requestUri);
                httpWebRequest.Timeout = 30000;
                httpWebRequest.Method = "HEAD";
                httpWebRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:64.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/64.0";
                httpWebRequest.Accept = "*/*";
                httpWebRequest.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;
                httpWebRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
                httpWebRequest.MaximumAutomaticRedirections = 4;
                CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();
                httpWebRequest.CookieContainer = cookies;
                HttpWebResponse httpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
                MessageBox.Show(httpWebResponse.StatusCode.ToString());

                if(httpWebResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
        catch (WebException e)
        {
            CommonCodes.WriteLog(e.ToString());
            return false;
}
```

--
It seems exception only occurring only when the url is http. Any ideas? I would like to achieve url is valid or not. I tried this in another pc which having differnt dns still same issue. The HttpWebResponse line is generating this exception. What is the best way to check url is valid or not?

```
http://1cosmetology.ru/gogyjod/wl62l4f.php?ybmqpftpd=vb-net-grid-control
```

Comment: Can you include the value of `url` that you're passing in? It looks like it's being parsed such that `requestUri.Host` is literally `http`, which is not being resolved to an actual endpoint.

Comment: @Brad I added the url. Please check it now.